# how to test an embedded async call

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am testing a function `parent()` that calls a function `slomo()` that returns a promise. I want to check that the code within the `.then()` is being executed.

```
function slomo() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve('good')
    reject('bad')
  })
}

child = jest.fn()

function parent() {
  slomo()
    .then((result) => {
      child()
    })
}

// TEST

it('runs child', () => {
  parent()
  expect(child).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

the result is:

> Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.

I have confirmed the child function IS being called via `console.log`, but it is being logged *AFTER* the test has completed.
I have tried passing and calling `done` inside the test but that did not correct the issue.
Maybe the above code is an anti-pattern and needs to be rewritten so that it can be tested?

Any help you can give me is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly found the root case of the problem, that test finishes earlier then async code, so [test should track async correctly](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous). But seems to you lost the promise b/c you don't return it, so:

```
function parent() {
  return slomo() // <<<--- add return 
    .then((result) => {
      child()
    })
}
```

Next you simply can add `done`:

```
it('runs child', (done) => { // <<<< --- add done
  parent().then(() => {
    expect(child).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    done(); // <<<< -- done should be called after all
  })
});
```

or just return the promise:

```
it('runs child', () => {
  return parent().then(() => {  // <<<--- return
    expect(child).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Alex - awesome blossom! 

while the _done_ answer did not resolve the issue for me (not sure why), the _return_ solution worked perfectly.

thank you for taking your time to help me with this problem.  bill

Comment: what if not returning the function is what I want ? there are more complex cases where the return value is not the `slomo` function but something else and for performance reason I just want fire the `slomo` function but not wait it ?

Comment: @Ella sounds like you already have in mind a solution for such case, feel free to post your answer then, I'll upvote it :). Could you please also share what is the  performance profit in just removed `return` statement?