# How to test calling to an async not-awaited function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, asynchronous, jestjs

I want to test the execution of both `fuctionUT` and an inner `async` unwaited function `externalCall` passed by injection. The following code is simple working example of my functions and their usage:

```js
const sleep = async (ms) => new Promise( (accept) => setTimeout(() => accept(), ms) )
const callToExternaService = async () => sleep(1000)

const backgroundJob = async (externalCall) => {
  await sleep(500) // Simulate in app work
  await externalCall() // Simulate external call
  console.log('bk job done')
  return 'job done'
}

const appDeps = {
  externalService: callToExternaService
}

const functionUT = async (deps) => {
  await sleep(30) // Simulate func work
  // await backgroundJob(deps.externalService) // This make test work but slow down functionUT execution
  backgroundJob(deps.externalService) // I don't want to wait for performance reason
    .then( () => console.log('bk job ok') )
    .catch( () => console.log('bk job error') )
  return 'done'
}

functionUT( appDeps )
  .then( (result) => console.log(result) )
  .catch( err => console.log(err) )

module.exports = {
  functionUT
}
```

Here there is a simple jest test case that fail but just for timing reasons:

```js
const { functionUT } = require('./index')

describe('test', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const externaServiceMock = jest.fn()

    const fakeDeps = {
      externalService: externaServiceMock
    }

    const result = await functionUT(fakeDeps)
    expect(result).toBe('done')
    expect(externaServiceMock).toBeCalledTimes(1) //Here fail but just for timing reasons
  })
})
```

What is the correct way to test the calling of `externaServiceMock` (make the test pass) without slowdown the performance of the `functionUT` ?

I have already found similar requests, but they threat only a simplified version of the problem.

[how to test an embedded async call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797105/how-to-test-an-embedded-async-call)

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your whole question. Try adding a timeout of 1ms or something so that the code has time to run.

Comment: You can test it with Jest fake timers and flush-promises. But the real problem is functionUT, it's flaky. It's `async` but has no `await`. I see no performance reasons here. You just leave a promise hanging, which is an antipattern. Even if you prefer to not wait for a promise, you could keep a reference to it so a caller could make use of it if needed, at least for testing purposes.

Comment: @EstusFlask I have updated the code so that `functionUT` is `async` because need to await something. Now the not awaited function `backgroundJob` is correctly managed for happy path and errors so, now is not flasky. Regarding the antipattern I don't know.. do you have docs about it? If there is possibility to await a func there is also the possibility to not await when is not needed.

Comment: @EstusFlask Not `await`ing an asynchronous function is fine if you don't need its results and do handle errors properly.

Comment: @Bergi That's true, but in this case results are needed, at least for testing purposes. The module does asynchronous side effect on import that cannot be tracked.

Comment: @Elia I see. No specific docs, just common considerations. In this case you may want to keep track of promises you create. Otherwise you import a module that does some job even after a test is complete, and you cannot easily track a specific moment when it stops. The same problem could appear later in production, depending on your specific case.

Comment: @EstusFlask this is a cache system where is very important to return asap and in background eventually save a copy of the result on the external cache system, but respond asap is magnitude order more important than store the result synchronously! I know this is corner case case but I have it and, I want to correctly test it or to know that there is a limit on what I can test.

Comment: A good thing about tests is that they reveal weak spots in design.  As I said, I see no performance issues here. If you have a promise, you have an option to chain or not chain it in a specific place. This doesn't mean it should be thrown away. In this specific case I'd possibly return  `{ status: 'done', backgroundJob: backgroundJobPromise }` and export `functionUT( appDeps )` result, at least for testing purposes, but probably for cleaner shutdown or else as well.

Comment: @EstusFlask I forgot to mention that option in my answer, though it's probably the best/cleanest solution. Do you want to add you own answer?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I ended up writing a post. It's also good to have backgroundJob mockable as you suggested, at least to thoroughly test the module

Answer (score 1):

You can't test for the `callToExternaService` to be called "somewhen later" indeed.

You can however mock `backgroundJob` and test that is was called with the expected arguments (before `functionUT` completes), as well as unit test `backgroundJob` on its own.

Answer (score 1):

If a promise exists but cannot be reached in a place that relies on its settlement, this is a potential design problem. A module that does asynchronous side effects on imports is another problem. Both concerns affect testability, also they can affect the application if the way it works changes.

Considering there's a promise, you have an option to chain or not chain it in a specific place. This doesn't mean it should be thrown away. In this specific case it can be possibly returned from a function that doesn't chain it.

A common way to do this is to preserve a promise at every point in case it's needed later, at least for testing purposes, but probably for clean shutdown, extending, etc.

```
const functionUT = async (deps) => {
  await sleep(30) // Simulate func work
  return {
    status: 'done',
    backgroundJob: backgroundJob(deps.externalService)...
  };
}

const initialization = functionUT( appDeps )...

module.exports = {
  functionUT,
  initialization 
}
```

In this form it's supposed to be tested like:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  let result = await initialization;
  await result.backgroundJob;
});

...

  let result = await functionUT(fakeDeps);
  expect(result.status).toBe('done')
  await result.backgroundJob;
  expect(externaServiceMock).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```

Not waiting for `initialization` can result in open handler if test suite is short enough and cause a reasonable warning from Jest.

The test can be made faster by using Jest fake timers in right places together with `flush-promises`.

`functionUT( appDeps )` call can be extracted from the module to cause a side effect only in the place where it's needed, e.g. in entry point. This way it won't interfere with the rest of tests that use this module. Also at least some functions can be extracted to their own modules to be mockable and improve testability (`backgroundJob`, as another answer suggests) because they cannot be mocked separately when they are declared in the same module the way they are.